# Mocking a Native Module when testing with Jest

Tags: testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to write tests for my application, but I currently get the following error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-localization/LocalizedStrings.js:17:35)
```

It seems that the error is caused by this line in [React-Native-Localization](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) that retrieves the device's locale:

```
var localization = require('react-native').NativeModules.ReactLocalization;
var interfaceLanguage = localization.language.replace(/_/g,'-');
```

The package is used in a `wrapper` that returns translated strings to the component, so the package isn't called directly. It looks something like this:

Component:

```
import wrapper from '../wrapper'

class component extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Text>{wrapper.getString(key)}</Text>
    );
  }      

  // ...
}
```

Wrapper:

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization'

class wrapper {

  constructor() {
    this.translations = new LocalizedStrings( ... );
  }

  getString(key) {
    return eval(`this.translations.${key}`);
  }

  // ...
}
```

React-Native-Localization:

```
var localization = require('react-native').NativeModules.ReactLocalization;
var interfaceLanguage = localization.language.replace(/_/g,'-');

class LocalizedStrings {
  // ...
}
```

The `localization` variable is set outside of the class and trying to set the variable like this doesn't work for me and returns the same error:

```
jest.mock('react-native-localization', () => {
  // This doesn't work
  const localization = { language: "en-US" }

  // This doesn't work either, because it hits the var initialization
  const rnl = require.requireActual('react-native-localization')
  rnl.localization = { language: "en-US" }

  // ...
})
```

Does anyone know how to mock this react native module?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing the component which depends on `wrapper`, you can `mock` the `wrapper` instead and have the `getString()` to return some `string` that you can use in your test. This way you don't use the actual `wrapper` class which depends on other libraries.

Comment: That's what i was afraid of. I didn't want to `mock` the `wrapper` as a lot of the things inside the `wrapper` class are actually used, meaning i'd have a lot of goodies to `mock` as well. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `var localization = require('react-native').NativeModules.I18nManager;` instead

Comment: This line comes from an npm package that I'm using. I'd prefer to avoid having to fork it. [Here's the line from the React-Native-Localization github repo.](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization/blob/master/LocalizedStrings.js#L17)

Comment: I know It, but if you change that I'm sure the problem is solved ;)